# About permutation with repeated identical elements.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

First up, I do know the general solution but somehow am unable to use it to solve this kind of problem. I am simply lost. The problem is like this:

`How many r arrangements of n items are possible with k identical elements?`

Had it been simply

`How many r arrangements of n items are possible?`

the answer is nPr.

Had it been simply

`How many arrangements of n items are possible with k identical elements?`

the answer is n!/k! (There could be any j number of k's, in which case, as I said, I know the formula is n!/(ki!*k2!...kj!))

However, I am lost how to use that to solve the problem when r and k are involved.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "how many r arrangements"?

Comment: To sum up, How many "ways" can you arrange "r" items of "n" amount. "k" would be the repeats.
Therefore:
{(r!)(n!)}/(k!)

Comment: @ant11 I don't know how to clarify it but I'll say It means exactly the same as it means in "regular" permutation questions whose answer is nPr. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split into cases depending on the number of "identical items" that are chosen. I will call these $k$ identical items "marked", and the distinct $n - k$ items "unmarked".

We try to find the number of $r$ arrangements with $i$ marked items. First, there will be $r - i$ unmarked items and $i$ marked items. There are
$$
\binom{n - k}{r - i}
$$
ways to pick $r - i$ unmarked items. There's only one way to pick $i$ marked items. With these $r$ items in hand, we can permute them. The number of permutations is
$$
\frac{r!}{i!}.
$$
Therefore, the number of $r$ arrangements with $i$ marked items is
$$
\binom{n - k}{r - i} \frac{r!}{i!}.
$$

Add these values up for all $i$ going from $0$ to $k$ to get the final answer:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n - k}{r - i} \frac{r!}{i!}.
$$

I'm not sure if this can be simplified...

Answer (score 0):

Tunococ explanations are perfect, but as it depends whether the amount of repeated elements k is below or not r; we should have:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{min(r, k)} \binom{n - k}{r - i} \frac{r!}{i!}.
$$